# Scipy.signal.find_peaks in c/c++

Tags: array-signal-processing

Hi guys I am trying to find a peak in waveform 1-d array data until I can find peaks in Python using scipy.signal find_peaks reference for that https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

but right now I want to implement the same thing with Arduino do you know how I can do it

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. Do you want to replicate the `scipy` algorithm in C? You can find the source code of the algorithm [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.2/scipy/signal/_peak_finding.py#L729-L1010) so you could just replicate that. Bear in mind that you will most probably need "auxiliary" functions to achieve that which you will have to implement too.

Comment: @ZaellixA I want to find peak in my waveform I was using scipy to find peak in python how can I use the same functionality in Arduino u

Comment: As I said, you have to somehow, copy/replicate the algorithm from `scipy` in C (or whatever Arduino is using). Alternatively, you could try implementing other algorithms found in the literature. I am not familiar with many of them as this is not my field of interest. I can only suggest some "naive" ones, such as trying to find a minimum of the first derivative (a finite-difference approximation can be used, which for "adequately" smooth functions could possibly suffice) and then maybe using a parabolic interpolation to find an inter-sample peak if needed. Otherwise, you'll have to (cont.)

Comment: (cont.ed) search in the literature for different methods. A rather simple "naive" algorithm is a kind of "smart almost brute-force" algorithm which looks like some sorting algorithms where you successively halve the search space until you find the peak. You can find this algorithm here (http://people.cs.bris.ac.uk/~konrad/courses/2019_2020_COMS10007/slides/01-Introduction-short.pdf) but you have to keep in mind that you may end up in a local extremum. I strongly suggest you either copy the `scipy` algorithm if you really want that or look for alternatives in the literature though.